# Map and Filter in a haskell function

Tags: haskell

I want to define the function doubleOdds :: [Int] -> [Int] that doubles every odd number in a list.

I've tried to write it like this

```
doubleOdds xs = map (2 *) . filter (funct xs)
        where funct x = x `mod` 2 == 0
```

but it is not working. Also how can I write it as an abreviattion in filter?

```
doubleOdds xs = map (2 * ) . filter (`mod` 2 == 0??)
```

Comment: "it is not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: check the signature of your `funct` and what you're providing as input.

Comment: @shury is my answer doing what you expected/wanted? If not can you please give an example of what behavior you are expecting?

Comment: By "it is not working", I think you mean that you're getting a type error. That's because `filter (funct xs)` should be `filter funct`; at least, if that's the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with I would advice you to write type-signatures first as those make the compiler-complains often easier to understand (and so your errors easier to see)

---

What about breaking out the part that causes trouble and using `map` afterwards:

```
doubleIfOdd :: Int -> Int
doubleIfOdd n
  | n `mod` 2 == 0 = n
  | otherwise     = 2*n

doubleOdds :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleOdds = map doubleIfOdd
```

this should work and is reasonable readable IMO

here is an example:

```
λ> doubleOdds [1..10]
[2,2,6,4,10,6,14,8,18,10]
```

so it double every number that was *odd* in the input-list - I think this is what you wanted

---

for the other part of your question: if you just use filter you cannot change the elements of the list - you can only make the list smaller (you can get a sublist of it)

---

as I was asked the predicate *is even* can be written pointfree as `` (== 0) . (`mod` 2) ``

(first take the remainder *mod 2* and then check if it's equal to `0` - remember: you have to read this from right to left because of how the composition is defined in math/Haskell)

```
isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven = (== 0) . (`mod` 2)
```

or

```
doubleOdds = map (2 * ) . filter ((== 0) . (`mod` 2))
```

but is this readable? ... I think not so probably this is somewhat better:

```
doubleOdds = map (2 * ) . filter (\n -> n `mod` 2 == 0)
```

also note that in this case the `xs` should not be on the left side as this would add an additional (unused) parameter and you would get a signature like this:

```
doubleOdds :: Integral a => t -> [a] -> [a]
```

instead of the wanted `[Int] -> [Int]` (note the `t`)

of course `isEven` already exists in the prelude - it's named [`even`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:even) so you could do

```
doubleOdds = map (2*) . filter even
```

or if you want the `xs`

```
doubleOdds = map (2*) $ filter even xs
```

etc. (there are *lots* of ways to write this)

note that this *interpretation* of your question would give you

```
λ> doubleOdds' [1..10]
[4,8,12,16,20]
```

Comment: it does what he describes in the first line of his/her question - I think it's ok to assume that the problem he has with his/her code is exactly that it does not what is stated in this very line - can I be wrong? **yes** - but is this worse then randomly downvoting instead of trying to help? ... Can we please keep the haskell part of SO friendly?

Comment: The description is ambiguous. The problem with the code is several type errors that OP neglected to mention in the question, but the intent is clear in the second version of OP's code. Why did you ignore that and answer a completely different question?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment but I can't really explain myself well in a comment. - I'm not much happier because I think you're rewarding bad behavior: OP was rude and you're spoonfeeding them code, under the guise of "being friendly".

Comment: not under the guise - for a very long time the Haskell subtag has been extremely friendly to newcommers - we don't have the problem of constant "write your code for me"-spam here - the *worst* thing is having people asking for homework - so as someone who wants to see Haskell more popular I try to be helpful and friendly - you see: I don't care about SO - I care about Haskell and FP

Comment: you might see this as a problem as many people here try to *police* this site to the point where it's dead for new people (see C# where I have a look from time to time) - personally I don't like this at all. And while I can do nothing about C# I can try to do quite a bit about Haskell still (as I said: the majority of people here is rather helpful... still)

Comment: btw: what is rude about not beeing able to express yourself clearly? Not everybodys first language is english (no - mines not too) and very often you can correctly guess - if not the OP will comment on your wrong assumption and in time you can help out if you are really interested in helping

Comment: What's rude is posting a question on a site with no effort to find out what constitutes a good question on the site, what the conventions are. It makes it seem like instead of taking the time to ask a good question, you'd rather just post whatever and waste the time of a million others who read the question and then have to figure out what it means, ask for clarification, repeat things already found in the Help section, etc. Asking the question, then going away for 12 hours, not responding to comments/requests for clarifications/etc, also fits in this pattern.

Comment: "waste the time" - as in discussing this with me here? Look I'm fine with you disagreeing (or with your downvote) - I just ask you keep Haskell friendly - comment on bad questions if you must or better: use your time and answer questions ;) (btw: there will not be millions reading the question - not when it's in the negative and accepted ... heck I doubt that there will be millions reading haskell questions even if they have 100+ votes)